# Ongoing issue with UIColor(named: "colorname")?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have seen some year old posts with similar issues, some claimed XCode 11 fixed it. I'm running XCode 12.3.

In a nutshell, this code works fine:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

but this code does not:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "green")
```

No errors are thrown, but the background always appears black, no matter what color string I pass.

Comment: `UIColor(named: "green")` loads colors from your `xcassets` folder, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877380-init) suggests.

Comment: @ Emilio: I'm just learning, so you may be right, but that's a link to the initializer documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The named parameter is for calling colours you have defined in your xcassets.

You define a color set like in the picture below and you can set light and dark versions of your colour which will be used depending if you have system dark mode enabled.

[image: picture of xcassets catalogue]

To use this colour I could do something like this.

```
textView.textColor = UIColor(named: "myBlueColor")
```